# Do android market test the developer application before publishing?

Tags: android, google-play

Do Android Market test the developer application before publishing?

Comment: Try: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - except for formal correctness of the Android manifest (if it adheres to the schema) -- if it is not correct you can't upload the app. But no content check like Apple seems to do.